# How can I load CSS files located outside the web root from within a custom module?

Tags: 7, theming, files

I need to store my css files at a location outside Drupal's path (e.g. /srv/assets/css/my_site/general.css). I attempt to achieve this using `drupal_add_css` but the browser loads them from:

`http://www.my-site.com/srv/assets/css/my_site/general.css` which results of course in 404 error.

Any idea how to load those *external (file system)* CSS files from within a module? note: I am using Linux.

Comment: BTW, I think `drupal_add_css` requires that the name of the CSS file begin with the modules names. For example, the custom module would require, the CSS file named custom.css. Not sure about this though.

Comment: It does not @PMagunia :)

Answer (score 0):

[`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) expects a path relative to the site root. As such, if you're going to use `drupal_add_css()` you need to add a path within webroot to access the file.

One way to that is to use a symlink. For example

```
ln -s /srv/assets/css/my_site/general.css sites/all/modules/my_module/css/general.css
```

As long as the file is readable by your web server, you can use drupal_add_css to reference your symlink path.

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/general/custom.css', array('type' => 'file'));
```